# unzip a LAR file, Edit the manifest.xml and then try to import the LAR file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, liferay, unzip

I have a bunch of LAR files that came with a installer.I need to import this LAR files. The portal version that the LAR files exported from have a different version then the portal I am trying to import into. The only workaround is do upzip the LAR files (file_name.lar), edit the manifest.xml and then zip the LAR files together with the updated manifest.xml and then import the files.Can someone help me out here, I have never opened/extracted LAR file before. If that helps I am using Redhat Linux. Thanks people!

Comment: I was able to open the lar files by adding .zip at the end of the file name and via Winzip. after making the changes I renamed it back to what it was.

Answer (score 2):

Well, good luck: The manifest in LAR files is not there in order to make it hard for you to import: There's still no backward compatibility designed into these files. The standard way is to import them in a Liferay with a matching version, update that version and export them again.

The version you're operating *might* or *might not* be compatible with the data in that file, but there's no guarantee. Worst case: The import works, but vital data (that was added during the upgrade) is still missing (but undetected, because such manipulation was not expected). In that case you might run into random problems later, and probably blame Liferay then.

That being said, `man zip` and `man unzip` tell you how to work with ZIP files. And, in the end, LAR files are ZIP files that just happen to have a different ending.

You should rather go back to the vendor that handed you the installer with the LAR files and ask for an updated version. *Especially* if this is a major upgrade (you're not mentioning if it's within the same version, different GA, or across versions). Not that I'd claim one would work better than the other.